# I am getting error while publishing app on Dart Flutter Google Play

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I made an application. I will publish this app on Google Play Store. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android I did all the steps here.

When uploading the `.aab` file, I get an error like this:

[image]

Why am I getting this error? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you are updating the app, you should use the same key to sign the app that was used previously.

Comment: @mkobuolys It's my first time to publish an app.

Comment: You provided a different sha1 hash from a key for the configuration than for the app build. Use only one key to sign the app bundle and set it's the hash in the console.